# Jmeter - How to set proxy if the website doesn't work on localhost port

Tags: jmeter

Is there any way to record in Jmeter if the web application is not listening to "localhost and 8080 port" (manual proxy configurations)?

Answer (score 1):

The url to the web application is best configured using a HTTP Configuration. There you specify the real URL where the application is deployed and which is avaiable to your client (where you run Jmeter)

Then you set Up a JMeter proxy and configure this proxy in your browser. And then you're ready to record.

See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf for details.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder) aka P[roxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server) which runs on localhost and listening to port 8080 is needed to capture requests from your browser and build JMeter script from them.

Application, you testing can be run at any host/port, the best place to control them is [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) Config Element.

Answer (score 0):

While configuring the proxy server for jmeter,there is an option to set the port and ip address for different protocols in Advanced option.